# Community Wiki posts don't change usernames if the user does

Tags: bug, community-wiki, display-names, locked-questions

If a user changes their username, it appears that Community Wiki posts of theirs don't update to display the new username.

See it in action: [a post by Adam (previously Anna) Lear on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/25284/146020).

(It's also possible that this is caused by the lock on the question, but it should be updated either way.